# What does it mean if Apache shows a blank page?

Tags: apache-2.2

Take a look at this: `http://86.18.30.197/`

As you can see, the screen is completely blank, I have no idea why this happens, I can access my website through `http://localhost/`. However, as you can see, the website on my external address is just a blank page. Is this a simple mis- configuration, as in, do I need to add anything to my config to make the website appear properly on my external IP?

Comment: Including the relevant bits (or the entirety) of your config in your question is going to help get an answer but this sounds likely to be a mis-configuration to me.

Comment: I just tried connecting to that IP address using telnet on port 80. I get no return data at all. I would guess that your firewall is configured to allow incoming connections to port 80, but not to return any data through the established connection. So, to start with, check your firewall settings.

Comment: Same here:
`Looking up 86.18.30.197  
Making HTTP connection to 86.18.30.197  
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.  
  
lynx: Can't access startfile http://86.18.30.197/  `

Comment: Also "Probably off topic. Improve and/or migrate to Super User". Except that for some reason it came from there.

Comment: But I am on DMZ so that shouldn't matter? I can host game servers and stuff no problem and it's the same thing right?

Comment: If you are on DMZ it should work. You need to check your httpd.conf file if Apache is listening on the correct interface (`Listen 80` and not e.g. `Listen localhost:80`). You also need to specify the correct `Virtualhost` (i.e. `VirtualHost *:80` and not `VirtualHost localhost:80`). You should also check you don't have an `allow from <local_subnet>` or something in the config restricting access to only internal ips. Some [examples](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/apache-2-basic-configuration-on-unix-like-systems/).

Comment: setting it to `Listen 80` makes Apache throw an error on startup

Comment: Would be handy to now **what** error? And what was the line before? Maybe you can mention that line and the whole virtualhost part in your question. (You can [edit](http://serverfault.com/posts/549912/edit) it in your question)

Comment: port 80 is already bound apparently, so I told it to listen on 225 instead.

Comment: If your Apache is listening on port 225 why do you get a website when you do a `http://localhost` (default port for http is 80). **That** is **not** the website of your Apache installation you just changed. Try `http://localhost:225`. Better yet, find out what installation uses port 80. At this time you have multiple webservers running. One on port 80 (which is defective for the outside) and one on 225. You could also forward port 225 on your router and use `http://86.18.30.197:225` from the outside.

Comment: 225 is port forwarded (I'm on DMZ) so you should be able to connect to that.

Comment: I couldn't find any ports open on `86.18.30.197`. But did you try `http://localhost:225` internally yourself on that pc? And if your on DMZ you shouldn't forward 225 because then you wouldn't get 225 in the DMZ. (Portforwarding overrules DMZ) And are you in a DMZ with your firewall down??? (not advised) Otherwise your firewall can still block things.